# Job application process full of bugs

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, jobs, feedback

I just applied for a job using this system, and it really needs improvement.

First, I'm using Firefox with Adblock Plus, and the "Cover Letter" dialog does not function.  I had to switch to IE. :shudders:

Next, I selected "use my Stack resume" and it opened a frame that could not be re-sized or scrolled.  My information didn't fit in the window, and even unselecting sections didn't help.  I changed it to upload my resume.

The next flaw was that my cover letter was reformatted without any line breaks.  I had to edit it and add double lines to get a line break.  These were then left as double line breaks.  It was truly odd behavior.

For a career website that caters to the best of us, I'm shocked to find flaws like this in the presentation.  I'm honored to be part of Careers @ SO, but I really expected such an important part of the process to be smooth and flawless.

Comment: It works fine for me using Firefox 14.0.1 with AdBlock Plus and NoScript installed. YMMV, I suppose.

Comment: Uh... Can't speak to the rest of this, but did you try disabling Adblock before giving up on Firefox? Personally, I've found that it causes more problems than it solves...

Comment: Sorry you're having troubles Jon. What version of Firefox were you trying to use? What other extensions do you have enabled? What version of IE did you switch to?

Comment: @Jon if you can still reproduce this functionality, would you please take screenshots and send it to us?  Also answering Jason's question would also be a lot of help.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry you had so much trouble.  Obviously that page is pretty important for Stack Overflow Careers and your experience is not the norm.

Regarding the specific bugs:

The bug with Adblock Plus is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).  Our suggested workaround is to disable Adblock Plus or add an exception for Careers.

The bug in IE with the unresizable / unscrollable frame is [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) and will be fixed.

The bug with the cover letter losing line breaks is [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) and we'd appreciate more information to help us reproduce it.